# KVM guest can't access internet

Tags: networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I have a number of Ubuntu guests running on an Ubuntu 16.04.6 kvm host.

Since I had to reboot my host, networking no longer works correctly. The host and guest can access each other, but my guest can't access the internet, and I can't access the guest from any other computers on the network. The host had Docker installed pre-reboot (may be relevant).

Using one guest as an example: Ubuntu 16.04.4

- Host IP: 10.0.10.2
- Guest IP: 10.0.10.13
- Guest KVM network settings:

  - Network source: Bridge br0: Host device eno1
  - Device model: virtio

Ping results:

```
colin@host:~$ ping 10.0.10.13
PING 10.0.10.13 (10.0.10.13) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.10.13: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.207 ms
```

```
colin@host:~$ ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=119 ms
```

```
colin@guest:~$ ping 10.0.10.2
PING 10.0.10.2 (10.0.10.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.10.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.257 ms
```

```
colin@guest:~$ ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
9 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 7999ms
```

Running tcpdump on host during tests (pinging host>guest, guest>world, guest>host) showing no reply:

```
colin@host:~$ sudo tcpdump -nni br0 icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on br0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
15:57:52.684722 IP 10.0.10.2 > 10.0.10.13: ICMP echo request, id 29324, seq 1, length 64
15:57:52.684953 IP 10.0.10.13 > 10.0.10.2: ICMP echo reply, id 29324, seq 1, length 64
15:57:53.683713 IP 10.0.10.2 > 10.0.10.13: ICMP echo request, id 29324, seq 2, length 64
15:57:53.683891 IP 10.0.10.13 > 10.0.10.2: ICMP echo reply, id 29324, seq 2, length 64
15:58:10.697087 IP 10.0.10.13 > 1.1.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 1620, seq 1, length 64
15:58:11.705736 IP 10.0.10.13 > 1.1.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 1620, seq 2, length 64
15:58:18.482031 IP 10.0.10.13 > 10.0.10.2: ICMP echo request, id 1622, seq 1, length 64
15:58:18.482061 IP 10.0.10.2 > 10.0.10.13: ICMP echo reply, id 1622, seq 1, length 64
15:58:19.481024 IP 10.0.10.13 > 10.0.10.2: ICMP echo request, id 1622, seq 2, length 64
15:58:19.481052 IP 10.0.10.2 > 10.0.10.13: ICMP echo reply, id 1622, seq 2, length 64
^C
10 packets captured
10 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

**Host config:**

```
colin@host:~$ ifconfig
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:fd:45:fc:85:d8  
          inet addr:10.0.10.2  Bcast:10.0.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2fd:45ff:fefc:85d8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:121153422 errors:0 dropped:715 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:65107786 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:172509978566 (172.5 GB)  TX bytes:16134433818 (16.1 GB)

br-df15cee8a6f6 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:74:28:3f:82  
          inet addr:172.20.0.1  Bcast:172.20.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:74ff:fe28:3f82/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:158611 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:402715 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:14673553 (14.6 MB)  TX bytes:62211023 (62.2 MB)

docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:85:6b:5d:cd  
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:fd:45:fc:85:d8  
          inet6 addr: fe80::2fd:45ff:fefc:85d8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:122992881 errors:0 dropped:14310 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:71313707 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:174820231625 (174.8 GB)  TX bytes:16827079661 (16.8 GB)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5163328 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5163328 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:3075521109 (3.0 GB)  TX bytes:3075521109 (3.0 GB)

veth142ebf2 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 72:71:cc:8a:71:ff  
          inet6 addr: fe80::7071:ccff:fe8a:71ff/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:111842 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:278641 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:11860403 (11.8 MB)  TX bytes:44222087 (44.2 MB)

veth4bb7c84 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:17:53:a6:ea:ca  
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc17:53ff:fea6:eaca/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:232661 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:18124977 (18.1 MB)

veth7a2885b Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d6:1c:ff:48:9d:e6  
          inet6 addr: fe80::d41c:ffff:fe48:9de6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:232659 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:18124809 (18.1 MB)

vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:7e:9d:e0  
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:fe7e:9de0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2800 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1339 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:267912 (267.9 KB)  TX bytes:2975296 (2.9 MB)
```

```
colin@host:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#auto eno1
#iface eno1 inet static
#address 10.0.10.2
#netmask 255.255.0.0
#gateway 10.0.0.1
#dns-nameservers 10.0.0.1

# Bridge
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address 10.0.10.2
        netmask 255.255.0.0
        gateway 10.0.0.1
        dns-nameservers 1.1.1.1
        bridge_ports eno1
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
```

```
colin@host:~$ sudo iptables -L -n -v
[sudo] password for colin: 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 87M packets, 121G bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 2630 packets, 264K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 5346 1299K DOCKER-USER  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 5346 1299K DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 1278  872K ACCEPT     all  --  *      br-df15cee8a6f6  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      br-df15cee8a6f6  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 1438  164K ACCEPT     all  --  br-df15cee8a6f6 !br-df15cee8a6f6  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  br-df15cee8a6f6 br-df15cee8a6f6  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 49M packets, 16G bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-df15cee8a6f6 br-df15cee8a6f6  0.0.0.0/0            172.20.0.3           tcp dpt:9000
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-df15cee8a6f6 br-df15cee8a6f6  0.0.0.0/0            172.20.0.4           tcp dpt:8181

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 1438  164K DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  br-df15cee8a6f6 !br-df15cee8a6f6  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 5346 1299K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      br-df15cee8a6f6  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 1438  164K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 5346 1299K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

**Guest config:**

```
colin@guest:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:7e:9d:e0  
          inet addr:10.0.10.13  Bcast:10.0.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fe7e:9de0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1057 errors:0 dropped:256 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2384 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2950816 (2.9 MB)  TX bytes:228448 (228.4 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:141 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:141 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:22109 (22.1 KB)  TX bytes:22109 (22.1 KB)
```

```
colin@guest:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.10.13
netmask 255.255.0.0
network 10.0.0.0
broadcast 10.0.255.255
gateway 10.0.0.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

I've been trying for weeks to solve this, but can't seem to make any headway.

Answer (score 11):

I received a comment on Reddit that pointed me in the right direction with this one: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxadmin/comments/bdy6sz/kvm_guest_cant_access_internet/

The problem is that Docker changes the default policy for the FORWARD chain in iptables to DROP.

A rule to allow traffic has to be added. Running this command added the required rule and fixed the issue:

```bsh
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: In my case, I was using the default NAT interface and had the same problem. Same solution:
`sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT`
Thanks for sharing!

Comment: My exact issue on Ubuntu 20.04 after installing Docker then trying to get the bridged network working for KVM.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! THANK YOU!!! I've been fighting with this same issue in various permutations for weeks... Why in the world does every guide covering kvm setup leave out this step??? Anyway, if you've on Ubuntu 21.10 and later you need to use: `sudo iptables-legacy -I FORWARD -i br0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT` (same command, just `iptables-legacy` instead of just `iptables`)

Answer (score 1):

One note to add to this, `iptables` has been deprecated and moved to `iptables-legacy`, yet docker's behavior persists:

> The problem is that Docker changes the default policy for the FORWARD chain in iptables to DROP.

I tried to use `iptables-persistent`, however that's appears to be loaded before docker, so docker still breaks the required forwarding rule above.

The best solution I've come up with is adding a systemd service that will run just after Docker to add this `iptables` entry.

Note today I'm also running the snap version of docker, if your sensible enough to run the non-snap docker, you can replace `snap.docker.dockerd.service` I think it's just `docker.service`.

##### `/etc/systemd/system/iptables-after-docker.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=iptables rule after docker
After=snap.docker.dockerd.service
BindsTo=snap.docker.dockerd.service
ReloadPropagatedFrom=snap.docker.dockerd.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/iptables-after-docker
ExecReload=/usr/local/bin/iptables-after-docker
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

##### `/usr/local/bin/iptables-after-docker`

```
#!/bin/bash

iptables-legacy -I FORWARD -i br0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
```

Don't forget to enable it:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable iptables-after-docker.service
```

Reboot and make sure you see the `br0` entry in iptables:

```
sudo reboot

# check that you now see the entry
sudo iptables-legacy-save | grep -i br0
# You should see you're `iptables` rule...
# Like: -A FORWARD -i br0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
```

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for sharing this  with a tweaks it works with archbox